# How do I get my Unix ps version number?

Tags: macos, unix, ps, version

I tried these, all without success:

- ps --version
- ps -version
- ps -v
- ps -V
- man ps, searching for version information

Specs:

- Mac OS X 10.8.2
- MacBook Pro 2009

Comment: I was able to find `PS(1)` in the man page, but I'm not sure that this provides sufficient version information for a bug report I'm making to Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ps` is part of the Mac OS X core distribution and released as open source by Apple. It is part of the `adv_cmds` package and has no version number on its own.

Unless you installed a custom `ps`, you can identify it by providing your OS X version number, or the version of the `adv_cmds` package on http://www.opensource.apple.com corresponding to your OS X version, e.g. version/release [149 for OS X 10.8.2](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-149/).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it doesn't want to tell its version. The best I can up with is `strings -a $(which ps)`. You'll find out that it is the FreeBSD version, mine says ps.c,v 1.110 2005/02/09.